# Image formatting in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to create the following page.

http://ielts.progmic.com/iOS/college.php?title=Royal+College+Of+Arts

In the link above...when I open it in Safari for iOS, the image is not being in centre. Like the heading and content is in centre with 15px padding. I want image to be in centre too with 15px space on each end.

Width of image is 610px and width of iPod Touch screen is 640px. Padding is set to be 15px. Still image is appearing as it is sticking to the right.

Here is the output I am getting in Safari for iOS.

[image: Top]

[image]
Please tell me how can I make the image appear in middle with proper 15px padding as other content is appearing. I hope I explained well. I am not good at explaining. Apologies in advance if I have missed something. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following on the image and add the style:

`width:100%; max-width:610px`

Final code should look like this:

`<img src="http://ielts.progmic.com/images/uni/1340408113.png" alt="college" style="width:100%; max-width:610px">`